# Как пишется "мало-помалу"?

Tags: орфография, наречия

Как правильно пишется наречие "мало-помалу" и почему?

Какие еще наречия пишутся подобным образом (через дефис)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно писать: "мало-помалу".
Наречия, где присутствует повторение одной и той же основы слова, но с разными окончаниями или приставками, пишутся через дефис.
Примеры: *крест-накрест, перво-наперво, волей-неволей*.

Comment: Как отметила @светлана, у наречий нет окончаний, корректно говорить о суффиксах наречий.

Answer (score 1):

***Составные*** наречия, образованные повторением одного и того же слова или соединением слов, связанных по смыслу и звучанию, пишутся через дефис:

***чуть-чуть, давным-давно, крепко-накрепко, волей-неволей, мало-помалу, сикось-накось, перво-наперво, еле-еле, нежданно-негаданно, быстро-быстро, видимо-невидимо, не сегодня-завтра, худо-бедно, тихо-мирно, постольку-поскольку...***
[**Правописание наречий через дефис** (пар.138)](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=73)

Исключения: точь-в-точь, бок о бок, на-гора, по-латыни.